# Eigenvalues & Eigenvectors out of non-numbers matrix

Tags: python, matrix, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I wanted to know if there is a way of getting the eigenvalues and eigenvector of a matrix A, when its not made out of numbers, in Python.

For example:

```
[[a,b]

 [c,d]]
```

I tried to make a program so that I could input any matrix to a website called matrixcalc.org, which can do the operation, but I got stuck at retrieving the values. Is there any module or way to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean non-number matrix? Do you want to compute eigenvalues symbolically, then plug numbers later?

Comment: Yep, i want it to find the expressions

Comment: Okay, your comment got me the answer i was looking for. The key word was Symbolically. (english is not my native languaje, so i never thought of prhasing the question that way).
I searched my prob with that keyword and found my answer. Using Sympy i can do what i got in mind. 
Thanks!!